# How to set x,y value in android application?

Tags: android, textview, java, adk

I am new to android application, using textview to set height and width but i didnot know how to set x,y value in android application, please help me

Thanks in Advance

```
Here i tried:

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Your country"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "x and y"?

Comment: similar to iphone application x and y value

Comment: android application dont have x,y value ahh

Comment: is it posiible to set xy value

Comment: I really did not understand what do you want, explain desired result please

Answer (score 0):

You have to set layout params for that for textview or any view in Android if you want to dynamically set width and height .

Answer (score 0):

You can use x and y position in **AbsoluteLayout** only.
Like this

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/button1" 
            android:layout_x="104dp" 
            android:text="Button" 
            android:layout_y="54dp"></Button>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

See other layouts in [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) site

Answer (score 0):

If I M Right that u want to set the height and width of a view(say textview)
You can do so in the xml layout.
for example :

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="DESIRED WIDTH"
    android:layout_height="DESIRED HEIGHT"
    android:text="Select Your country"/>
```

just set ur value for height and width.

Or if u want to set in in run time u can do it like that

```
TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.setWidth(DESIRED WIDTH);
textView.setHeight(DESIRED HEIGHT);
```

DESIRED HEIGHT & DESIRED WIDTH is up to you.

hope it help.

Comment: so is this what u looking for ??